# Blackberry BrowserFieldHistory Does Not Get Updated by history.go(-1) javascript

Tags: javascript, blackberry, history, browserfield

Have an application that is using a BrowserField.  The web site that is rendered within it all works fine except for an issue where pages have a back button that executes the following javascript: history.go(-1);

The page itself in the browser does go back one but the BrowserFieldHistory object is not updated and there are no requests to either handleNavigation or handleResource (I guess because the page is already cached).

Because of this the application cannot determine when the user has gone all the way back to the first page loaded and subsequently the Blackberry hardware back key cannot be used in the same way it operates in the device browser application (pressing back either goes back a web page or if pressed while in the first page closes the screen).

Any ideas why history.go(-1) is not reflected in the history stack and/or why the application doesn't receive handleNavigation/handleResource events?

I am developing on Win7 (32bit) in Eclipse Helios, BB 1.5 JDK on the 9800 (Torch) simulator (OS 6.0.0 of course).

Thanks

James

Comment: Did you try this with `history.goBack()` as well?